# Applying conditions for buyers and sellers to get the data from kite

Tags: python

I have the logic but cannot convert into the code
The logic is :
If number of buyers are more than 10% of the number of the sellers then print out the number of buyers
Can anyone please write the code??
Thankyou, Hatim

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: i have used the api the fetch the data, however i was getting an error that it cannot compare 2 dictionaries at the same time

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.  You can take each number as input and just do a simple if statement.  Multiply sellers by 0.1 to get 10% of them and then just see if the number of buyers is greater than that. If it is, print the number of buyers.

```
buyers = int(input())
sellers = int(input())

if buyers > sellers * 0.1:
    print(buyers)
```

Comment: Hey, thankyou for answering the question however there is one problem, which is that we cannot input the data, it has to take the data from the site and then calculate if it is 10% up or not,